# Lei è or lei sei when talking to someone in formal way

Tags: word-usage, grammar, pronouns, formal

It may seem a stupid question, but I was surprised that we use lei as "you" formally. I don't understand why using same pronoun for she and you, and do we use lei è like she is or lei sei?
Excuse my ignorance  I only know the basics

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Well, although nowadays most people use "_lei_" meaning "she", the grammatically correct translation of "she" (subject) would be "_ella_", while "_lei_" translates both "her" (complement) and the formal "you" (subject). When used as subject, "_lei_" always requires the third person singular.

Comment: I would strongly discourage teaching foreign students with a basic or intermediate level that *ella* is a correct translation of *she*, because this is never used in current Italian, unless in ironic or extremely formal contexts.

Answer (score 4):

When addressing someone formally with "lei", you
must conjugate the verb in third person singular. In the chapter "Il verbo [1]" of the book *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri*, by Federica Colombo, you can read:

> Per la forma di cortesia si usa la 3ª persona singolare.

Some examples from this book are the following:

> Signora, **ha** fame? 
> Professore, lei **è** egiziano?
> Signora, **prende** un caffè?